# Is it possible to find the listening port of a remote client connecting to my server?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Once an incoming TCP connection is established, through a `java.net.Socket`, I can find my listening port and the port that was created for this connection. Is there a way; when the client connected to me is also a server listening for connection; to know on which port this remote client/server is listening ?

It feels like a wrong usage of sockets. And in my case, it is to identify client/server entities composing our application. So I could send some kind of greeting message when establishing an outgoing connection for identification.
But I'm curious whether this is possible or not, and I found no answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When a client connects to your server it opens a port for you to send data to the client. This connection automatically connects so that writing to the socket from the server will send to the correct client port. If you would like to know what it is `Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()` which will return a `SocketAddress` that can be cast to an `InetSocketAddress` which has a `getPort()` method.

If the server has a different port open that you wish to make use of, you will have to send the port from the client to the server.

For example, if computer A is running and SSH server on port 1234, and it wants to inform computer B so that computer B can SSH to computer A, and computer B is listening on port 1337, then computer A can connect to port 1337 on computer B, send something along the lines of "I'm listening on 1234" which is read by B, and then can be used by B to SSH into A.

Comment: The java.net.Socket has a getPort() that returns the remote port number to which this socket is connected.  No need to call getRemoteSocketAddress() and cast to InetSocketAddress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know I can do things this way but it's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to know if the server can retrieve client's informations (client's listening port in my case) through the initial socket connection.